# Using web services in VB.net, sending an API key and other information to the server.

Tags: vb.net, web-services, soap, wsdl, api-key

I am new to web services in VB.net.  I have imported the WSDL into the Visual Studio 2010, but using the .net 2.0 "Web References" framework instead of the new "Service References".

I simply need to learn how to pass my API key and one other piece of information through the API to the server.  This is all that I have.   What code to I need to add to

a) Send the API Key
b) Send the Database Mode String

```
Public Sub Call_Web_Service_Method()
    Dim CallWebService As New PersonService.Header()
    Dim sPostAPIKEY As String = CallWebService.APIKey()
    Dim sPostDatabasemode As String = CallWebService.DatabaseMode

End Sub
```

I've been looking for two days now on how to send an API key to a server in VB.net and I have not found anything.  Please help a newbie.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it your own web service or a web service that you don't have control over? What method on the web service do you want to call? The web service probably has a method where you can provide the api key and the database mode as parameters?

Check out these simple guides on how to consume a web service i VB.NET
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2761/Consuming-Web-Services-from-a-Win-Forms-Applicatio
http://www.fryan0911.com/2009/05/vbnet-how-to-consume-web-services.html